# How to handle wrong requests?

Tags: struts2

I've developed a site in struts2, but often, there comes many wrong requests. After 20 or 30 hrs, my server is getting stuck. I want to handle this type of error.

There are given some errors displayed in the server:
1)There is no Action mapped for namespace /operators-in-java/operators-in-java/text and action name javascript. - [unknown location]
.........
2)There is no Action mapped for namespace /super-keyword/text and action name javascript. - [unknown location]

3)There is no Action mapped for namespace /operators-in-java/operators-in-java/history-and-features-of-java/text and action name javascript. - [unknown location]
etc.

I've performed global exception handling as given below:

```
    <global-results>
<result name="excepHandler">/handler.jsp</result>
</global-results>

<global-exception-mappings>
<exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Exception" result="excepHandler"/>
</global-exception-mappings>
```

But it doesn't handle, this type of error. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to use wild cards. Simply make a action for "*" and have that direct to your error page. All actions with more specific names will override that case so it should be straight forward.

Comment: Please specify the code because in web.xml file * goes to the controller named StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter

Comment: @SonooJaiswal: i believe you know about where to configure you actions, but `Quaternion` has suggested is to create a action for this use-case and let this action catch all such case where you can redirect that to common error page

Comment: I got it, thank you very much! I can't explain, how much happy I am! Thanx once again!

Comment: @SonooJaiswal please mark the answer as solved (the check mark on the left under the #votes) if indeed this has solved the issue.  I've noticed you have a couple other questions which are not marked as solved.  By marking answers as solved it helps the people who frequent these subjects to know where they need their attention so more people can be helped.

Answer (score 0):

Does your clients get the 404, not found error?
You could configure your web.xml to redirect to an error page when somebody requests an invalid resource.

```
 <error-page>
  <error-code>404</error-code>
  <location>/notFound.html</location>
 </error-page>
```

But, I would try to fix whatever is causing the incorrect requests, instead of creating a catch all action. Apparently you've configured struts2 to handle every request, I would check on that first.